# Existence of a subgroup

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory

I want to show that a group has no subgroup of index 4 and 6 by using character table. But, I didnt find which argument must be used. I show that it is simple using KerX. Then, what should the following step be?

Thank you

Comment: If $G$ has a subgroup $H$ of index $n$, then $V = \mathrm{Ind}^{G}_{H}(1)$ is an $n$-dimensional representation of $G$ over $\mathbf{Q}$ which contains (by Frobenius reciprocity) a unique copy of the trivial representation. Hence, taking the complement $W$ of the trivial representation in $V$, one obtains a representation (over $\mathbf{Q}$ and hence with traces in $\mathbf{Q}$) of dimension $n - 1$ which contains no copy of the trivial representation. From the character table, $G = \mathrm{PSL}(2,7)$ has no such representations of dimensions less than $6$.

Comment: That is because the smallest non-trivial representations are a pair of conjugate representations of dimension $3$ (which don't have traces in $\mathbf{Q}$) and a representation of dimension $6$. This argument shows that the smallest possible $n$ which could occur is $n = 7$, which happens to be the correct answer in this case.

Comment: (FWIW, $G$ contains a copy of $S_4$ with index $7$, and $\mathrm{Ind}^{G}_{S_4}(1)$ decomposes as the trivial representation plus the irreducible $6$-dimensional representation.)

Comment: That’s good! Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

We can exploit your knowledge that $G$ is simple.

If $H\le G$ is of index $k$, then $G$ acts transitively on the set of the $k$ cosets by left multiplication, giving rise to a homomorphism $G\to S_k$. If $k>1$, this homomorphism cannot be trivial (consider the action by any $g\in G\setminus H$). As you already know that $G$ is simple, the homomorphism must then be injective.
For $k=4$, this is impossible because $4!<168$. For $k=6$, it is impossible because $7\nmid 6!$.

Comment: Yes, this is group theoretical approach. But, How can I use character table to show it?

Comment: This does not answer the question because it does not use character table.